# How do I write slash and quote together (e.g. \") inside a swift string?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a html string which contains **\"** (slash and quote together). I want to replace **\"** with **"** (quote) using this method:

```
let slashAndQuote = "How to write here slash and quote together (something like this '\"')"
let slash = "\""
let str = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(slashAndQuote, withString: slash)
```

I am not able to write slash and quote together within string. Please let me know better solution.

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML string really contains backslashes and that this is not an artefact of the debugger output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape each individual special character you want in the String with a `\`. In your example it would look like this:

```
let slashAndQuote = "How to write a slash and quote together, (something like this '\\\"')"
print(slashAndQuote)
```

This gives an output of:

```
How to write a slash and quote together, (something like this '\"')
```

You can do the same for just the slash and quote as well:

```
let slash = "\\\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the backslash and the quote. So, `"\\\""`.

After '\' the next special character will be displayed as a string. so the first '\' escapes '\' and the second '\' escapes the quote ".

So, your code should look something like this:

```
let slashAndQuote = "How to write here slash and quote togater (somthing like this '\"')"
let slash = "\\\""
let str = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(slashAndQuote, withString: slash)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

print("\(("\""))")